# constrain StackView inside ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I am trying to implement a `UIStackView` inside a `UIScrollView` but I am having problems constraining it correctly. These are my `constrains`:

```
func setUpViews() {

    view.addSubview(backgroundImage)
    view.addSubview(backButton)
    view.addSubview(theScrollView)
    theScrollView.addSubview(theStackView)
    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(emailTextField)
    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(anzeigeNameTextField)
    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(wishlistHandleTextField)
    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(passwordTextField)
    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(passwordWiederholenTextField)
    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(documentsLabel)
    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(signUpButton)
    view.addSubview(eyeButtonOne)
    view.addSubview(eyeButtonTwo)

    backgroundImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

    backButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    backButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    backButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    backButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

    theScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 120).isActive = true
    theScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    theScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    theScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 400).isActive = true
    theStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    theStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    theStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    theStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    anzeigeNameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    wishlistHandleTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    passwordWiederholenTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    documentsLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    signUpButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    eyeButtonOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordTextField.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    eyeButtonOne.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordTextField.centerYAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    eyeButtonTwo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordWiederholenTextField.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    eyeButtonTwo.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordWiederholenTextField.centerYAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

}
```

When the `View` is presented the StackView is wrongly placed (1st picture) and only after A `textfield` is selected it moves to the center like it should always be (2nd picture).

[image][image]

Other issue is that when I scroll the view it is scrollable on the x and y axis but I would limit that so the user can only scroll up or down.

And last but not least the `eyeButtons` are not being displayed at all.

I guess I have a misunderstanding on how to constrain inside a `StackView` inside a `ScrollView`. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Your stackView has 30-pts leading and trailing, so its width should be **-60**:  `theStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -60).isActive = true` Start with that change.

Comment: And, your posted code shows `theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 400).isActive = true` ... I assume you don't really want it 400-pts from the top of the scroll view?

Comment: thanks! That fixed 2/3 issues :D `400` was just for testing on how it behaves when scrolling :) Any ideas on the `eyeButtons`? they are not even in the `View Hirarchy`..

Comment: never mind.. I fixed that as well, was a mistake somewhere else. thanks for your help :)

Comment: The `eyeButtons` *should* be there the way you have your code (they show up for me). However, assuming you want them to be related to the password fields, you may want to change the hierarchy, such as making the `eyeButton` a subview of the text field.

Comment: Or... set the `eyeButton` as a `.rightView` ... see the **Managing Overlay Views** section here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield

Comment: like I said that was another problem in my code :)